# Program seems like it stops working halfway after a certain amount of values is outputted

Tags: python

My code:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)
findNumber = 0
startingnumber = 100000
def mainfunc():
   global startingnumber, findNumber
   while(findNumber == 0):
      print(startingnumber)
      if (startingnumber % 11 == 0):
          if (startingnumber % 12 == 0):
              if (startingnumber % 13 == 0):
                  if (startingnumber % 14) == 0:
                      if (startingnumber % 15 == 0):
                          if (startingnumber % 16 == 0):
                              if (startingnumber % 17 == 0):
                                  if (startingnumber % 18 == 0):
                                      if (startingnumber % 19 == 0):
                                          if (startingnumber % 20 == 0):
                                              findNumber=1
                                          else:
                                              startingnumber = startingnumber + 10
                                              mainfunc()
                                      else:
                                          startingnumber = startingnumber + 10
                                          mainfunc()
                                   else:
                                      startingnumber = startingnumber + 10
                                      mainfunc()
                              else:
                                  startingnumber = startingnumber + 10
                                  mainfunc()
                          else:
                              startingnumber = startingnumber + 10
                              mainfunc()
                      else:
                          startingnumber = startingnumber + 10
                          mainfunc()
                  else:
                      startingnumber = startingnumber + 10
                      mainfunc()
              else:
                  startingnumber = startingnumber + 10
                  mainfunc()
          else:
              startingnumber = startingnumber + 10
              mainfunc()
      else:
          startingnumber = startingnumber + 10
          mainfunc()                                                             
mainfunc()
print('found number:', startingnumber)
```

This use of this program is to calculate the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20

I know this program works since when I plug in the correct number in 'startingnumber', the program detects it and works. However, my problem here is that the starting value increases by up to ≈25,000 then the program stops working.

For example, if I set startingnumber to 10,000, the program runs until ≈35,000 then just stops working. If I set startingnumber to 100,000, the program runs until ≈125,000 and stops working.

Can someone tell me why?

I also know that there a lot simpler ways to do this but I plan on working on that after I figure out why this program doesn't work

Thanks

Comment: It's difficult to follow the program flow between the nesting, while loop and recursion, but you have a recursive function that calls itself in the majority of branches from within a loop. It loops like this will crash with a `RecursionError` eventually from exhausting the stack.

Comment: I'll note that a `for` loop would **greatly** simplify this program. The nested `if`s and recursion are both unnecessary.

Comment: What exactly is it that you think those recursive calls to `mainfunc()` are doing, that the `while` loop isn't already doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a much more pythonic way of solving this problem:

```
def smallest_divisible(n):
    while True:
        factor_check = tuple(n%i==0 for i in range(2, 21))
        if all(factor_check):
            return n
        n += factor_check.index(False) + 1
```

Here, `n` is the starting point.  You could just set it to 1 if you want.  This code spits out 232792560.
There are opportunities to make this much faster by tracking some primes.